# Pass @variable between controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

I have `Project` and `ProjectSetting` models with following associations:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :project_setting
end
class ProjectSetting < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
end
```

In `projects_controller` I have:

```
def show
  @project = Project.find(params[:id])
  @project_setting = @project.project_setting
end
```

So I'm using `@project_setting` form in `@project` show page and I need to update `@project_setting` from this page.

In `project_settings_controller` I have:

```
def update
  @project = Project.find(params[:id]) #problem is here
  @project_setting = @project.project_setting
  if @project_setting.update_attributes(params[:project_setting])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to project_path(@project) }
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

But `@project` variables in these controllers aren't the same:

In `projects_controller#show` it is `Project` with ID 26 and in `project_settings_controller#update` it finds `Project` with ID 1

So I need to pass `@project` variable from `projects_controller#show` to `project_settings_controller#update`.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your show.html.erb you can pass the variables back to any controller. For example

```
<%= link_to "Update project setting", 
  :controller => "project_settings", 
  :action => "update", 
  :project => @project %>
```

will send the parameter "project" filled with the @project variable.

If you are in a form tag, you can send the variable with a hidden field tag:

```
<% hidden_field_tag("project", @project) %>
```

I hope, this helps.

Answer (score 2):

`params[:id]` in `project_settings_controller` contained `@project_setting.id`
If you want to get `@project.id` from params, you should to write in `routes.rb` nested path:

```
resources :projects do
    resources :project_settings
end
```

And then `project.id` is available in `params[:project_id]`.
Example in [rails_guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources)